# problem with SQL Server and connecting to C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm new to programing. I want my program connect to C# but I'm getting this error:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**:
>   'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

My code:

```
namespace HesabDarinAnbarDari
{
   public partial class FrmTanzimat : Form
   {
      public FrmTanzimat()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=(local);initial catalog=HesabDariDB;integrated security=true");
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

      private void FrmTanzimat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      }

      private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          cmd.Connection = con;
          cmd.Parameters.Clear();
          cmd.CommandText = "insert into Tanzimat (NameFroshqah, Tel, Mobile, Address. Tozih) values (@a, @b, @c, @d, @e)";

          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtNameFroshgah.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", txtTel.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", txtMobile.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtAddress.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", txtTozih.Text);

          con.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          con.Close();
          MessageBox.Show("done");
      }
   }
}
```

SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tanzimat] 
(
    [idTanzimat]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NameFroshgah] NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [Tel]          NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [Mobile]       NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [Address]      NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Tozih]        NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tanzimat] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idTanzimat] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Can you connect to db by pther means? Sql server manager or alike?

Comment: For starters put your connection string in the config file instead of hard coded in the application. Is this code running on the same machine as the sql server? Also, you would do yourself a favor to give your parameters useful names instead of a,b,c. Last but not least, look at your datatypes and choose them appropriately. You do NOT need nvarchar(max) for address. I don't know of any address on earth that needs that many characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you are not connecting to SQL Server, which suggests a problem with your connection string or server.  Try replacing (local) with (localhost) if you have an instance of SQL Server running locally (but be aware that this connection string will break as soon as you try to run your code on a different computer.)

If that doesn't work, go to the Server Explorer pane (View -> Server Explorer).  Right-click Data Connections and choose Add Connection.  Use that wizard to find your server and click Test Connection to make sure you're good to go.  Click OK.  Now in server explorer, click on your new data connection to select it, and look in the properties pane.  You will see the connection string there.  You can copy and paste from there into your code.

Comment: thank you <3 now im getting this error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.'

Comment: `insert into Tanzimat (NameFroshqah,Tel,Mobile,Address.Tozih)values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e)` - you have 5 parameters and only 4 fields to stick those values in.  Should the period in between Address and Tozih be a comma? In other words, change `Address.Tozih` to `Address, Tozih`

Comment: Thank you so much i was blind

Comment: No problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

When this exception throw, it means C# can't find your Data source `(local)`

Replace the `(local)` with your server name in the Sql Server Management Studio .

Comment: my sql server name is DESKTOP-AEJT71E\SQLEXPRESS .but i cant put it in the code.i also tried with SQLEXPRESS and getting the same error

Comment: Why you can't place it to your code ? Place the `DESKTOP-AEJT71E\\SQLEXPRESS` 'With two back slashes' to your Data source

Comment: i did but still same error :( .im  using System.Data.SqlClient .

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a sql server on the other computer or not?

Comment: You have 4 fields and 5 values `(NameFroshqah,Tel,Mobile,Address.Tozih)` Count = 4 And  `values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e)` Count = 5

Comment: Thank you so much i was blind